# jvm.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, jvm

I have Visual Studio C++ Project, which has to call some java functionality. I'm going to use JNI. I have specified additional include directories:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\include

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\include\win32

and additional library directory

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\lib

and was able to compile needed code. But I still cannot run it because of the next error:

The program can't start because jvm.dll is missing...

Anyone help please that what i should do now...?? Is there any way to specify the path for JVM.DLL ???

Comment: Did you follow the JDK installation instructions? Did you read about how to deploy applications built against the JDK?

Comment: Yes .. JDK is working fine in other platforms...  BoundaryImposition

Comment: That's not what I asked you.